# A good introductory book on cryptography

Tags: reference-request, cryptography, books

Can anyone suggest me some good books on cryptography? I have just starting studying cryptography but I know elementary number theory, abstract algebra and algorithms. Also please mention the difficulty level of the book.

Comment: Andrew Tannenbaum's Computer Networks has a chapter on cryptography & gives a really good introduction into the subject. Though it is only one chapter, I would say its good for beginners & difficulty level being easy.

Comment: Please see [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-about-list-questions) and [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/145/our-first-list-question) meta discussion about the validity of list questions.

Answer (score 6):

"Introduction to Modern Cryptography", Jonathan Katz and Yehuda Lindell. This is a great book for learning about provable security.

And for actual crypto protocols and algorithms, there's always the classic: "Handbook of Applied Crypto" by  Paul van Oorschot, A. J. Menezes, and Scott Vanstone. This is more a reference book than a textbook. And its available free of cost on one of the authors web-pages.

Comment: Why are these books recommendable? What does set them appart from others? What is their level?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what the purpose is, I personally read the [A very short introduction to Cryptography](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0192803158) which was a perfect guide to someone knowing nothing about this subject.
If your purpose is to begin applying readily available algorithms this is a good book. If you want to get in deap and look at the functioning of algorithms you will need something more thorough

Comment: Why is this book recommendable? What does set them appart from others? What is its level?

Comment: I haven't read the other, but I suspect they are quite thorough. This book is a good alternative as a first introduction to the subject.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend "[Understanding Cryptography](http://www.crypto-textbook.com/)", Christof Paar & Jan Pelzl, if you are self teaching some cryptography. Why? Since it can be really hard to just follow a textbook by yourself, professor Christof Paar uploaded his lectures on youtube ([Introduction to Cryptography by Christof Paar](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1usFRN4LCMcfIV7UjHNuQg/videos)) so you can have a more complete experience.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to say that **Applied Cryptography** by Bruce Schneier is the best I have come across. It's a good introduction, but at the same time have a detailed level.

Comment: @Juho Bruce Schneier. I recommend *Cryptographic Engineering* over *Applied Cryptography*, it's more up-to-date and has more usage considerations. AC is mostly a catalogue of algorithms.

Comment: Why is this book recommendable? What does set them appart from others? What is its level?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO a very good book for you may be: J. Hoffstein, J.Pipher, J. H. Silverman, An Introduction
to Mathematical Cryptography. ISBN 976-1-4419-2674-6. It is published 2010 in the Springer series Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics.

Comment: Why is this book recommendable? What does set them appart from others? What is its level?

Comment: The level could be inferred via its being included in the mentioned (if I don't err, normally considered sufficiently satisfactorily edited) series of the Springer-Verlag. It is IMHO sufficiently comprehensive, over 500 pages, fairly up-to-date, containing treatments of elliptic curves and lattices. Since from OP I believe it is more the math side of crpytography rather than the more "practical" side that the poster is interested, I recommended this title rather than books by Schneier etc.